# Input difficulties with \usepackage{devanagari}

Tags: languages, input, input-encodings, indic

I am using the standard miktex package

```
\usepackage{devanagari}
```

however, using the same input examples as written in the file manual produces very different results, i.e. there is a duplication of vowels nearly after every letter. instead of devAnAM priyaH, the output becomes daeva a a na a a m parai ... etc.

The document in full is:

```
\documentclass[A4,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\input dnmacs

    {\dn devaanaa.m priya.h}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably misunderstanding how the `devanagari` package works.

I saved your example in a file `gyalten.tex` and typeset it with `pdflatex` (but removed `\input dnmacs`, which is foreign to LaTeX) and got

[image]

which is possibly what you mean by `daeva a a na a a m parai`.

If I change the name of the file to `gyalten.dn` as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    {\dn devaanaa.m priya.h}

\end{document}
```

then run the script `devnag` from the command line

```
devnag gyalten
```

so that a file `gyalten.tex` is produced. Running `pdflatex` on this preprocessed file gives

[image]

which might be the expected result. Sorry, I know nothing else about Devanagari.

Comment: Yes, the output is exactly how it should be. Wonderful. Now I'll try and reproduce that. Thank you,